# Code not writing output to file

Tags: python, python-2.7

This code is not writing the output to the file. It only dumps the data in the .data file not the output which should be a range from 0 to 1.

```
import math

f = open('numeric.sm.data', 'r')
print f


maximum = 0

# get the maximum value
for input in f:
    maximum = max(int(input), maximum)
f.close()

print('maximum ' + str(maximum))


# re-open the file to read in the values
f = open('numeric.sm.data', 'r')
print f

o = open('numeric_sm_results.txt', 'w')
print o

for input in f:
    # method 1: Divide each value by max value
    m1 = float(input) / (maximum)
    o.write(input)
    print repr(input.strip('\n')).rjust(5), repr(m1).rjust(5)

o.close()
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
o.write(input)
```

should be

```
o.write(str(m1))
```

and probably you want to add a newline or something:

```
o.write('{0}\n'.format(m1))
```

Comment: i think this adds the newline you are talking about
print repr(input.strip('\n')).rjust(5), repr(m1).rjust(5)

Comment: @user2428261 No this prints something to the console, but not to the file.

Comment: ok, it shows a TypeError: expected a character buffer object at this write command

Comment: at the line you advised to modifyo.write(m1)

Comment: @user2428261 You are right, I fixed my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it gave the results but the newline thing that you advised is not working

Comment: @user2428261 Why not? Does it also throw an error?

Comment: not actually, it prints the output without a new line
do u think
    o.write('{0}'.str(m1))
will work?

Comment: @user2428261 No, that wouldn't make sense. My code works for me and I don't see any error.

Comment: `import math

f = open('numeric.sm.data', 'r')
print f


maximum = 0

# get the maximum value
for input in f:
    maximum = max(int(input), maximum)
f.close()

print('maximum ' + str(maximum))


# re-open the file to read in the values
f = open('numeric.sm.data', 'r')
print f

o = open('numeric_sm_results.txt', 'w')
print o

for input in f:
    # method 1: Divide each value by max value
    m1 = float(input) / (maximum)
    o.write(str(m1))
    o.write('{0}\n'.format(m1)
    print repr(input.strip('\n')).rjust(5), repr(m1).rjust(5)

o.close()
f.close()`

Thats wat u suggested. ryt?

Comment: @user2428261 Of course you should not use both `write` statements...

Comment: hmm...ok, i tried `o.write(str(m1) + "\n")`. This did not work either

Comment: Make use of ´with´ context manager.

Answer (score 0):

It's because You have file handler called `f`

but it just points to an object, not the contents of your file

so,

```
f = open('numeric.sm.data', 'r')
f = f.readlines()
f.close()and then,
```

and then,

```
o = open('numeric_sm_results.txt', 'w')

for input in f:
    # method 1: Divide each value by max value
    m1 = float(input) / (maximum)
    o.write(input)  # Use casting if needed, This is File write
    print repr(input.strip('\n')).rjust(5), repr(m1).rjust(5)  # This is console write

o.close()
```